# Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller

Even though I am entering the value of username but whenever i press the submit button this error occurs

And other form fields are working just fine.

```
 $values = array('email' => $request->email,'username' => $request->user_name, 'password' => $request->password);

 $test = DB::table('users')->insert($values);
```

Comment: Does $request->user_name return a value? If not, double check the field in you form.

Comment: yes it does return a value

Comment: ...so is it `username` as mentioned in the description, or is it really `user_name`, or could it be `user-name`, or something else? I'd check that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Laravel uses `$name` as the fillable field for a user's name.  If you are changing this to '`$username`' on the **User** model, make sure you make it fillable:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'email', 'password',
];
```

If it isn't fillable on the model, Laravel will return a null value to the database no matter what you fill in.  As the DB field `username` is probably not nullable in your code, this is likely the source of the error.