# cannot update data laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I have error when updating data on laravel,

> (Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'nama_user' cannot be null (SQL: update `users` set `nama_user` = ?, `email` = ?, `password` = $2y$10$.xYE1yE99DkN2OdyCecI1OkIVqSdJQb8XIuumv7ALUiLxZLM7eX.K, `role` = ?, `status` = ?, `users`.`updated_at` = 2021-08-19 02:59:55 where `id` = 10) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\mysmk-be\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 692)

this is my controller code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $users = ManagemenUser::where('id', $id)->first();
        $users->nama_user = $request->nama_user;
        $users->email = $request->email;
        $users->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $users->role = $request->role;
        $users->status = $request->status;
        if($users->save()){
            return response()->json([
                "status" => "success",
                "message" => 'Berhasil Menyimpan Data'
            ]);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                "status" => "failed",
                "message" => 'Gagal Menyimpan Data'
            ]);
        }        
}
```

and im using postman form data for the request

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| nama_user | ihsan20 |
| email | ihsan@gmail.com |
| password | 12345678 |
| role | 1 |
| status | 1 |

Comment: It seems there is no data in your request. Do a `return $request->all();` so it returns what is coming.

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ  i got null when i do return $request->all();

Comment: make sure you are sending form data from the postman.

Comment: Are you sure it returns null and not an empty array?  also make sure you are using this class `Illuminate\Http\Request` and not another

Comment: Is `nama_user` in your Model's `$fillable`?  See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909816/error-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-username-c, or [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you must send the form data from the postman. It should be in tab and format as shown in screenshot[image: postman request example]

After that try to print dd($request->all()) and check all request parameters along with values showing there or not.
It working for me properly.